# TG Schola – missing symbol textbullet

Tags: fonts, symbols, warnings

I am using the `tgschola` package which provides the TeX Gyre Schola font. When I run a .tex file containing an `itemize` environment through `pdflatex`, I get the following warning:

```
[Font] Font shape `OMS/qcs/m/n' undefined using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead for symbol    `textbullet'. (page 1)
```

Is there a way of fixing the warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the package textcomp. `\usepackage{textcomp}`. Then `\textbullet` will use TS1 encoding.