# \textbullet and CM sans serif: font shape undefined

Tags: fonts, symbols, warnings, computer-modern

The following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \sffamily
  \textbullet
\end{document}
```

gives me the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbullet' on input line 4.
```

I believe this warning is because cmss does not define a bullet. The TeX FAQ [recommends ignoring the warning](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fontunavail). Some answers on this site (e.g. [TG Schola – missing symbol textbullet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14425/tg-schola-missing-symbol-textbullet)) suggest the [`textcomp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package. The documentation of the `textcomp` package says "Note that there is now a textcomp.sty in the LaTeX distribution, and the original package is now little used (if at all)."

If I want to get rid of the warning is `\usepackage{textcomp}` the correct way to go? Does that use the "original package" or the one in the LaTeX distribution (I am using TeX Live 2011)

Comment: Excellent question! You really did your "homework" before asking it, way to go!

Comment: @doncherry thank you for the compliment and also for the helpful edits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
  \sffamily
  \textbullet
\end{document}
```

Is, as you indicated the right thing. The log file should show something like

```
(........texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
```

`base` in the path and `Standard LaTeX` in the package description both indicating the core distribution

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\TS1/cmss/m/n/10
```

indicating you have a bullet from the extended ss font.

Comment: Could you add a sentence or two on what "the core distribution" is (What else or where else could a package be?) and on what the other two lines mean (in particular `TS1`, which seems to be a font encoding, but how is it different from `T1`?)?

Comment: There is a little information about `TS1` encoding in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22550/textcomp-makes-textbullet-smaller-when-using-helvet-font. Not enough for me to understand yet, but at least enough to get me started.