# Warnings with beamer class and itemize

Tags: beamer, symbols, fontsize, warnings

I'm getting the following annoying warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 16.

...
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.
```

I tryed to reduce the a minimal working example as much as possible:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item bla
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14425/tg-schola-missing-symbol-textbullet

Comment: Thanks! The number of warnings can be reduced with that method. I edited my minimal example and the warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To completely remove those warnings, you should

1. load the `textcomp` package to provide the missing `\textbullet` symbol (as done in the edited version of your question);
2. use a scalable font like `lmodern` to provide a font size of 4pt.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item bla
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```