# Duplicate figure numbers in Beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering

I am trying to have multiple Beamer slides discussing the same figure, and have the figure have the same Figure number across multiple slides. I am not sure how to do this. In the following example, I would like to have multiple slides discussing "First figure". If I simply create two different figures, clearly they will have different numbers. If I label them with the same label, I get

`LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.`

What I want is something like below, but the second slide to say "Another interesting point about Fig. 1". How can I do this? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Talk about Fig. 1}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    My first figure
    %\includegraphics{something.png}
    \caption{First figure}
    \label{fig:first-fig}
  \end{figure}
Interesting point about Fig. \ref{fig:first-fig}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Talk about Fig. 1}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    My first figure
    %\includegraphics{something.png}
    \caption{First figure}
    \label{fig:first-fig-2}
  \end{figure}
Another interesting point about Fig. \ref{fig:first-fig-2}.
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: My beamer currently produces this.]

Comment: I get the expected result and no warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although using floats like `figure` inside a [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation seems wrong, you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Talk about Fig. 1}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering\includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First figure}\label<1>{fig:first-fig}
  \end{figure}
  \only<1>{Interesting point about Fig.~\ref{fig:first-fig}.}%
  \only<2>{Another interesting point about Fig.~\ref{fig:first-fig}.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The above relies on the overlay-aware `\label`, as well as other overlay aware things like `\only`. You specify a single `frame` and add some slide-specific content using the appropriate notation.

The use of [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm) stems from [Warnings with `beamer` class and `itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84315/5764). `lmodern` provides scalable fonts at the sizes required by `beamer`.